# javascript_include_tag not working

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

i'm using a javascript_include_tag in one of my 'partial' rhtml files. yet, when the page loads, I get an error in firebug saying that the class included in the javascript file was not defined. Basically, the javascript file is not getting added. I have kept the js file in the public/javascripts folder

Please help

Comment: can you add example of your code that is adding the js file?

Comment: If you view the page's source, do you see a link to the file? Maybe it's being included after the file that requires it.

Comment: @Beerlington: I saw the page's source code. The link for the js file is not present.

Comment: code used by me: <%= javascript_include_tag 'rule_loader' %>

Answer (score 2):

First, what version of rails are you running?  I know with my version of rails(3.1.1) the javascript_include_tag defaults to the **app/assets/javascript** directory not the public/javascripts folder.  Placing files in the assets/javascript folder should allow you to properly link to them in a similar fashion.

This will include all js files residing in the assets/javascript folder and should already be at the top of your views/layout/application.html.erb file.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

Also any subdirectories will be included by the above tag.  Hope this helps.